# Passing data to a running CUDA kernel

Tags: synchronization, cuda, gpu

Is there a way to pass data to a running CUDA kernel? I think it can be done by launching the kernel asynchronously and using mapped pinned memory. With this approach, I can probably write in the GPU device memory and the kernel code can read from there.

This approach has a major synchronization problem: how can individual threads synchronize on specific memory locations?

Comment: Nope, can't be done. There is no guarantee of memory coherency if the host tries modifying memory being accessed by a running kernel.

Comment: I think if you're running cuda version 2 and above, there's this feature called zero-copy which allows kernel to directly access host memory. I don't know if this will work but perhaps your kernel can poll the host side to achieve what you need. The drawback is that reading from the host side is quite expensive.

Comment: The question is: why would you want to do this? Even if gamerx's solution works (I have heard of it but never tested it myself) there is no apparent benefit, it will only get really slow.